# What happens to the hard drive's head on abrupt shut down?

Tags: hard-drive, power

Suppose my hard disk is up and running. Suddenly there is a power outage when the hard disk head was on top of some sector trying to read some very large portion of data(busy moving for the upcoming 2 seconds). Now suppose after this instant I open my hard drive and observe the position of the head. Will the head be on top of some sector or at the idle position. (Does it have some small backup power to return it to the idle position). If the head position is **not** on the initial idle position is that in any way a problem that needs to be handled or it does not matter at all ? At some point the system has to know where the head is, in order to make the next move.

Comment: Even if heads weren't parked, a disk manufactured in modern times would surely have some method either of determining the current position, or of simple resynchronzation by jumping as far back as it can – which is how floppy drives make their power-on noises; that's the heads resetting their position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally modern HDDs have a mechanism that automatically parks the heads on power loss, fully removing them from the spinning platter. You hear a *click* from the inside when that happens.

If you're viewing the drive's S.M.A.R.T. stats, there's a counter labelled "Power-off Retract Count" or "Emergency Retract Count" telling you how often this has happened.

I'm not sure what the exact mechanism *is*; [this other post](https://superuser.com/questions/153399/can-a-power-loss-break-an-hard-disk/153414#153414) says powered by inertia of still-spinning platters. Personally I expected either springs or something magnetic.

(*Older* disks decades ago apparently used to have a [landing zone](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/does-head-parking-cause-any-wear-or-is-this-a-myth.2370103/#post-36092465) on the platter itself, and it's quite possible that they would just leave heads in place if the OS didn't get a chance to park them.)

> At some point the system has to know where the head is, in order to make the next move.

That's a different question with its own solutions.

One possible way is to reset the head position by auto-parking it, as above. Auto-parking is primarily meant to protect the disk from physical damage (in case the heads hit the platters during transport), but it's also a way to return to a known location, although not very precise.

Some old floppy-disk drives use a slightly different method where they attempt to move the heads *as far back as possible and then some* – e.g. a 80-track drive would always attempt to move the heads a full 80 tracks back, even if it results in bashing the head against the wall 80 times (this could be heard as a brief *brrr* noise on every power-on).

Finally, another method is to have something that *indicates* the exact position of the heads, e.g. a [servo track](https://www.fujitsu.com/global/documents/about/resources/publications/fstj/archives/vol42-1/paper11.pdf) that can be read directly by the heads themselves to know where they are on disk (both linearly and rotationally), or an [encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_encoder) in simpler cases.

I *think* modern HDDs use a "servo track" for this purpose; even though they have automatic head parking for physical safety, it doesn't offer quite enough precision, especially at the high data densities of modern HDDs.

Comment: Depends on how the arm actuator works. I think in modern drives it's a spring that constantly pushes towards a park location, and the actuation is via an electromagnet that counteracts this spring force (more power moves the arm further from park, less power lets the spring bring it back closer to park). When power is lost, the electromagnet is completely off and the spring forces the head to the park position - hopefully before the platters stop spinning and the air cushion preventing contact dissipates. This page seems to confirm that: http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/actParking-c.html